# make a change in each group after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Let we have a dataframe like

```
names = ['bob', 'alice', 'bob', 'bob', 'ali', 'alice', 'bob', 'ali', 'moji', 'ali', 'moji', 'ali', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob']
times = [21 , 34, 37, 40, 55, 65, 67, 84, 88, 90 , 91, 97, 104,105, 108]
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : names , 'time_of_action' : times})
```

We would like to `groupby` it by `name` and in each group consider times from 0. That is in each group we want to subtract min-time_of_action in that group from all times of that group. how could we do this systematically with pandas?

Comment: you wouldve made it way easier if you put the expected otuput

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. One way would be to iterate over the (key.group) pairs of the groupby objects and perform your operation. Do you have a more specific question concerning any attempts you have made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am correct then you want this:

```
df['new time'] = df['time_of_action']-df.groupby('name')['time_of_action'].transform('min')
```

---

**df:**

```
    name    time_of_action  new time
0   bob     21              0
1   alice   34              0
2   bob     37              16
3   bob     40              19
4   ali     55              0
5   alice   65              31
6   bob     67              46
7   ali     84              29
8   moji    88              0
9   ali     90              35
10  moji    91              3
11  ali     97              42
12  bob     104             83
13  bob     105             84
14  bob     108             87
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df['new_time'] = df.groupby('name')['time_of_action'].apply(lambda x: x - x.min())
df
```

Output:

```
     name  time_of_action  new_time
0     bob              21         0
1   alice              34         0
2     bob              37        16
3     bob              40        19
4     ali              55         0
5   alice              65        31
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered but here's mine

```
import pandas as pd
names = ['bob', 'alice', 'bob', 'bob', 'ali', 'alice', 'bob', 'ali', 'moji', 'ali', 'moji', 'ali', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob']
times = [21 , 34, 37, 40, 55, 65, 67, 84, 88, 90 , 91, 97, 104,105, 108]

df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : names , 'time_of_action' : times})

def subtract_min(df):
    df['new_time'] = df['time_of_action'] - df['time_of_action'].min()
    return df

df.groupby('name').apply(subtract_min).sort_values('name')
```

As others have said I am kind of guessing as well