# How to add a column or change data in each group after using group by in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-analysis

I am now using Pandas to handle some data. After I used `group by` in pandas, the simplified DataFrame's format is [MMSI(Vessel_ID), BaseTime, Location, Speed, Course,...].

I use

```
for MMSI, group in grouped_df:
    print(MMSI)
    print(group)
```

to print the data.

For example, one group of data is:

```
             MMSI         BaseDateTime       LAT        LON  SOG  COG
1507  538007509.0  2022-12-08T00:02:25  49.29104 -123.19135  0.0  9.6   
1508  538007509.0  2022-12-08T00:05:25  49.29102 -123.19138  0.0  9.6
```

I want to add a column which is the time difference of two points.

Below is the Output I want

```
             MMSI         BaseDateTime       LAT        LON  SOG  COG   Time-diff
1507  538007509.0  2022-12-08T00:02:25  49.29104 -123.19135  0.0  9.6   0.05(hours)
1508  538007509.0  2022-12-08T00:05:25  49.29102 -123.19138  0.0  9.6   Na
```

So I use the code below to try to get the result:

```
for MMSI, group in grouped_df:
    group = group.sort_values(by='BaseDateTime')
    group['new-time'] = group.shift(-1)['BaseDateTime']
    group.dropna()

    for x in group.index:
      group.loc[x,'time-diff'] = get_timediff(group.loc[x,'new-time'],group.loc[x,'BaseDateTime']) # A function to calculate the time difference


    group['GROUP'] = group['time-diff'].fillna(np.inf).ge(2).cumsum()
    # When Time-diff >= 2hours split them into different group
```

I can use print to show group['GROUP'] and group['time-diff']. The result is not shown after I tried to visit grouped_df again. There's a warning showing that my `group` in `grouped_df` is just a copy of a slice from a DataFrame and it recommend me using `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value` instead. But in this case I don't know how to use `.loc` to visit the specific [row,col].

At the very beginning, I tried to use

```
  grouped_df['new-time'] = grouped_df.shift(-1)['BaseDateTime']
  grouped_df.dropna()
```

But it shows

```
'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment
```

Now my solution is create an empty_*df and then concatenate the groups in `grouped`*`_df` step by step like this:

```
df['time-diff'] = pd.Series(dtype='float64')
df['GROUP'] = pd.Series(dtype='int')
grouped_df = df.groupby('MMSI')
for MMSI, group in grouped_df:

    # ... as the same as the code above
    group = group.sort_values(by='BaseDateTime')
    group['new-time'] = group.shift(-1)['BaseDateTime']
    group.dropna()

    for x in group.index:
      group.loc[x,'time-diff'] = get_timediff(group.loc[x,'new-time'],group.loc[x,'BaseDateTime']) # A function to calculate the time difference


    group['GROUP'] = group['time-diff'].fillna(np.inf).ge(2).cumsum()
    # ... as the same as the code above

    frame = [empty_df, group]
    empty_df = pd.concat(frames)
```

I am not satisfied with this solution but I didn't find a proper way to change the value in `grouped_df`.

I'm now trying to use the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65148307/make-a-change-in-each-group-after-groupby) to handle the DataFrame before group by.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do? If you want to modify the original dataframe, then don't use a loop.

Comment: Note that `2022-12-08T00:05:25`-`2022-12-08T00:02:25` is 3 minutes (0.05 hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a loop, directly go with [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['BaseDateTime'])

df['Time-diff'] = (s.groupby(df['MMSI']).shift(-1)
                    .sub(s).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
                  )
```

Or [`groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['BaseDateTime'])

df['Time-diff'] = (s.groupby(df['MMSI']).diff(-1)
                    .mul(-1).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
                  )
```

Output:

```
             MMSI         BaseDateTime       LAT        LON  SOG  COG  Time-diff
1507  538007509.0  2022-12-08T00:02:25  49.29104 -123.19135  0.0  9.6       0.05
1508  538007509.0  2022-12-08T00:05:25  49.29102 -123.19138  0.0  9.6        NaN
1509  538007510.0  2022-12-08T00:02:25  49.29104 -123.19135  0.0  9.6       0.05
1510  538007510.0  2022-12-08T00:05:25  49.29102 -123.19138  0.0  9.6        NaN
1511  538007511.0  2022-12-08T00:02:25  49.29104 -123.19135  0.0  9.6       0.05
1523  538007511.0  2022-12-08T00:05:25  49.29102 -123.19138  0.0  9.6        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

using `group by` and `apply` can solve your problem

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Assuming you have a DataFrame named 'df' with columns ['MMSI', 'BaseDateTime', 'LAT', 'LON', 'SOG', 'COG']

def get_timediff(row):
    return (row['new-time'] - row['BaseDateTime']).total_seconds() / 3600.0

def assign_group(row):
    return row['time-diff'] >= 2

df['BaseDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BaseDateTime'])  # Convert 'BaseDateTime' to datetime format

# Sort the DataFrame within each group based on 'BaseDateTime'
df['new-time'] = df.groupby('MMSI')['BaseDateTime'].shift(-1)
df = df.sort_values(by=['MMSI', 'BaseDateTime'])

# Calculate the time difference
df['time-diff'] = df.apply(get_timediff, axis=1)

# Assign a group label based on the time difference
df['GROUP'] = df.groupby('MMSI')['time-diff'].transform(assign_group).cumsum()

# Drop the 'new-time' column if you don't need it anymore
df = df.drop(columns=['new-time'])

# Display the result
print(df)
```

This code converts the `BaseDateTime` column to `datetime` format, sorts the `DataFrame` within each group based on `BaseDateTime`, then calculates the time difference using `apply` and assigns a group label based on the time difference.

Now, you should have a `DataFrame (df)` with `time-diff` and `GROUP` columns.